# LoaderManager callback not called on screen rotation

Tags: android, android-cursorloader, android-loadermanager

I have a FragmentA in my MainActivity. In FragmentA i'm using a Cursor Loader.

```
class FragmentA: BaseFragment(), LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
    activity.loaderManager.initLoader(1, null, this)
    Log.d("FragmentA", "onActivityCreated")
}   

override fun onCreateLoader(id: Int, args: Bundle?): Loader<Cursor>? {
    return CursorLoader(activity, AppContentProvider.URI, null, null, null, null)
}

override fun onLoaderReset(loader: Loader<Cursor>?) {
}

override fun onLoadFinished(loader: Loader<Cursor>?, data: Cursor?) {
    Log.d("FragmentA", "onLoadFinished")
}
}
```

When I open my app it works correctly, my content is loaded. But If I rotate my device, nothing is displayed.

Here are my logs:

```
FragmentA - onActivityCreated 
FragmentA - onLoadFinished
// Device rotation
FragmentA - onActivityCreated
// Device rotation again
FragmentA - onActivityCreated
FragmentA - onLoadFinished
```

So far I was using Fragment and it worked nicely. But I just changed to support Fragment and now I'm experiencing this weird behavior.

Why my Loader callback isn't called when orientation change?